# Python limit key input per second

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi that is setup to run different videos depending on the key press on a keyboard. If someone accidentally hits two keys at once, it causes the unit to temporarily freeze up. What is the best way and code to limit one key press of keys x,y,z for two seconds?

Comment: How are you capturing key presses?

Comment: Currently I have modified the keyboard.xml file to run scriptx.py when x is pressed, and so on.

Comment: There is a bug in raspberry pi's hardware stack that means keyboard interrupts arn't always handled or even missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just record the time when each keypress comes in, and store the last couple. If the time of the next keypress is shorter than your required threshold, just ignore it.

Comment: How would that be possible to do and prevent the keypress from going to the OS?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but your program is reading the keypresses. You don't want to (and probably can't easily) stop them from reaching the operating system, but your logic is free to ignore them if they arrive too soon after the last one.